# passing a bluetoothSocket to another activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, bluetooth

I am trying to send a bluetoothSocket to another activity, but since it isn't `Parcelable` nor `Serializable` I am kind of at a loss about what to do.

I haven't found anything else on this though I've searched to find an example somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Managing a `BluetoothSocket` in an `Activity` sounds like a bad idea as the `BluetoothSocket` will be somewhat tied to the `Activity` lifecycle. You should consider moving the `BluetoothSocket` to a `Service` instead. The different activities that need to use the `BluetoothSocket` can then do so through the `Service` instance. You also get an extra benefit: your `BluetoothSocket` can remain active even though your application is not in the foreground.

Comment: Thanks, will try this too, but I fixed it making a class which extends from Application and adding it in the manifest, in the class I put a getter and a setter for a BluetoothSocket and get it in each of the Activities with my_application_class app = (my_application_class) getApplication();

Would this present any kind of problem? Is it better to use Service?

Comment: I guess you can make it work like that though it might not be the prettiest solution. If you need your socket to remain open when your application is not in the foreground, you need to use a service.